# Update entry based on datas found in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a total noob to this. Basically I'm trying to lower the queries number for faster execution time (got 100,000's queries and it takes forever to run the script)

Let's say I have something like this:

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts SET categorie=XXXX WHERE design=12345
```

To find the value of `XXXX`, I have to do this:

```
SELECT categorie FROM shop_designs WHERE design=12345
```

How can I do that with just ONE query? Currently I have to do 2 queries, so making that change would make the page load 2X faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heck clean em all up at once!

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts t
JOIN shop_designs d
ON d.design = t.design 
SET t.categorie = d.categorie
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts SET categorie = d.categorie
FROM shop_designs d
WHERE design = 12345
AND d.design = 12345
```

This should work for you.
This is assuming that "design" is a distinct key (that is when you search WHERE design = 12345 only one row is returned)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but many different entries in shop_tshirts share the same design (but in shop_designs, there should be only 1 entry per design)

Answer (score 0):

don't set categorie on the table shop_tshirts - in fact remove this field completely.

then when you need the categorie field from the shop_tshirts table JOIN the shop_tshirts and categorie tables to get it

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM
    shop_tshirts
JOIN
    categorie ON categorie.design=shop_tshirts.design
WHERE
    design=12345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts SET categorie=XXXX WHERE design=(SELECT categorie FROM shop_designs WHERE design=12345)
```

or:

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts AS t1
    LEFT JOIN shop_designs AS t2 ON t2.design=t1.design
SET t1.categorie=t2.categorie
WHERE t1.design=12345
```

but i not think you problem is in query of course until i can see you database and you script i cant tell but try to add index in both table for column design

Answer (score 0):

Update entry based on datas found in another table

```
UPDATE shop_tshirts t
JOIN shop_designs d
ON t.design = d.design
SET t.categorie =   d.categorie
WHERE t.design = 12345
```